# HTML onChange for SELECT not working on IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm developing a form with PHP and jQuery.

Here is the link:

http://www.yamaha-motor.com.pe/extreme/php/yamaha/registro/FrmRegistro01.php

It works fine on Firefox but not on IE.

What can you advise me??

Thanks

Comment: what doesn't work? it works for me in Firefox and IE.

Comment: Always include which version of IE you're having trouble with, there are numerous engines at play and widely used, with various quirks each.

Comment: If you're talking about the checkmark appearing when you select from the list, works for me in IE8, IE7 and Quirks Mode. Is there some other behavior you're expecting?

Comment: I'm having troubles when adding with jQuery a listener to multiple SELECT in HTML.

Those events are never added or trigered on IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

The fix was to not to do something like:

```
$('select#cbxMeses').attr('onchange', "javascript:fn_mesSeleccionado()");
```

... and do this:

```
var select1 = document.getElementById("cbxMeses");
select1.changed = false;
select1.onchange = fn_mesSeleccionado;
```

Apparently IE tries to execute all JavaScrpit code before all DOM elements are rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Well your page is so complex and littered with cut-and-paste code it's difficult to know what exactly the problem is you want to demonstrate. But a brief flick through the script reveals that you are sniffing for `addEventListener` and sniffing for IE in particular, and doing completely different things for each, a lot of which are simply commented out. So what do you expect?

```
$('select#cbxMeses').attr('onchange', "javascript:fn_mesSeleccionado()");
```

This is an obvious wrongness. Firstly because event handler attributes should not have `javascript:` at the start (that's only for `javascript:` pseudo-URLs, which should also **never** be used).

But in any case this isn't at all the right way to attach event handlers to elements; it won't work in IE, and it's ugly and inefficient to be putting JS code in strings. Use a function (either a function name or an inline `function() { ... }`) and one of jQuery's event binding methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cbxMeses').change(fn_mesSeleccionado);
    $('#cbxAnos').change(fn_anoSeleccionado);
    ...
});
```

This works everywhere! There's no need to sniff browsers at all!

Comment: I already found the solution... The problem was because of a problem when you use scripts on IE.

IE tried to execute a JS Script before all the DOM was loaded,,, so the event listeners that I added via jQuery to some SELECT elements where not working but now they are... By the way... If has nothing bad on placing a string with the name of a function on a listener... It's the same